# ATLR 4 - Iterative vs Recursive

Tags: recursion, antlr, depth-first-search

Assume this Abstract Syntax Tree:

[image]

I imagine that ANTLR will traverse this tree using a recursive algorithm (depth first traversal.) I will evaluate this tree many times (for example, 10MM times.)

Instead using a recursive algorithm for traverse this tree, i could use a iterative (using my own stack). For the puporse of performance, i suppose that iterative algorithm will perform much better. Does ANTLR really use a recursive traverse? Is it really a performance problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 4 Visitors definitely use a recursive traversal by default. ANTLR 4 listeners use a walker, and the current implementation of [`ParseTreeWalker.walk`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/9275a0ecad44892c69a11ae1c127a757c6689b99/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTreeWalker.java#L51-L53) also uses a recursive traversal.

In high-performance scenarios, the listeners and visitors are designed for convenient use during the conversion of ANTLR 4 parse trees to some other execution representation, such as a custom bytecode interpreter (e.g. StringTemplate 4), dynamic code generation to ECMA-335 or JVM bytecode, or JIT/AOT compilation to native code. It is not a performance problem because the parse trees are only evaluated a few times.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What i am trying to do, is create an engine capable to execute a SQL statement. My first approach will be evaluate the AST many times. Do you know what representation uses for an SQL statement?  I am really lost..